# Configure two gmail servers in one Rails 3.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmail, actionmailer

Is it possible to configure two gmail servers in one rails app? I did a web search and didn't come up with anything. I would prefer not to get involved in using postfix instead of gmail unless that is the only way.

In my production.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'domain1.com',
  user_name:            'serv@domain1.com',
  password:             '************',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true }
```

I'd like to configure a second server for my gmail server at serv@domain2.com. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: How do you plan on using the 2nd server? As a fallback in case the first one fails?

Comment: @Beerlington, no. Without getting into a long, full explanation... there are two different kinds of accounts that access our site. I want to use different return email addys. In most mail clients setting "from" or "return_path" in the mailer doesn't insure that a reply is going to the address indicated. It goes to the account from which the email was sent.

Comment: Hmm, I've never had issues with the "from" address not working when I set it in the mailer. Have you looked at something like [http://sendgrid.com/](http://sendgrid.com/)? They have an API that might give you more control.